# Is it possible to hide part of an adaptive web design on smaller screens?

Tags: website-design, responsive-design, front-end-development

This is the News page of my firs adaptive website.

[image]

The full height is shown (the scroll-down part is also included).

The terracotta sections on the horizontal line are for placing news feed images, 
and I want to hide that section on the mobile-adapted version.

Is it possible or it may cost additional work for the developers?

Comment: I wrote [an article](http://zachsaucier.com/blog/blog/2014/08/11/responsive-design-primer/) on the subject of responsive design that may be useful for you. This question is too broad. If you have specific questions about your design please update your question to include them

Comment: First off, the term is Responsive, not Adaptive.  Second, yes, this is very possible.  If you want to hide certain elements at different screen resolutions, you will need to use Media Queries in your CSS and add the property display: none;

Comment: First off, Thank you for the answer, second let me tell you that "Adaptive" as I have mentioned in my question means that the website adapts to the screen size in real-time, and "Responsive" as you corrected me is a web design approach to make the site adaptive =)

Comment: Hi Sonique, I edited the question's title to better reflect what I think you're asking. If I'm wrong, don't hesitate to revert or improve on my [edit]s!

Answer (score 4):

This should be possible somewhat easily if you instruct your web developer accurately. They'll have to give the bar a certain so-called `class` and include a media query to hide it on smaller screens.

for example:

html

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar-element">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="bar-element">
    ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

css:

```
@media only all and (max-width: 660px) {
    .foo {
    display: none;
    }
}
```